# Detect JavaScript warnings

Tags: javascript

I have a site that opens another tab/window temporarily.  Once it's no longer relevant or needed, its script calls `window.close()`.  However, the user may occasionally have that URL bookmarked or access it in some other way manually rather than arriving there as the result of the first/main window programmatically opening it.

In such cases, I note that the `.close()` call results in a warning on the console (Chrome 48).  I understand it's a security feature, and am totally fine with that.

What I'd like to do is to detect that the call didn't work (or won't) and do something else instead - in my case show the user a flash message saying they should close the tab/window manually.

I tried the below code, but am realizing that since no exception was thrown, the catch is never hit.  Is there a way to do what I'm wanting to?

```
try {
  window.close();
}
catch (e) {
  showFlashMessage('Error closing tab.  Please close it manually.'); // Never gets here :(
}
```

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) doesn't give clues but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536367%28VS.85%29.aspx) claims there's a return value to check. No idea if it's an IE-only feature.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should be able to detect whether your window is a popup or not by inspecting [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener). If there is no such other window, you probably can't `.close()` yourself.

Comment: Please note: Windows Phone browser does not support window.opener (tested with Microsoft Edge 25.10586.36.0).  It is also not supported in IE if the opener is in a different security zone.

Comment: Hm, maybe try setting something like `window.open(…).opener = window;` yourself in that case. Of course, if you are in different security zones (is that a Microsoft-ism for the SOP?) it never will work.